# Find who & when deleted a line in a function using GIT

Tags: git, git-log, git-blame

I have some ruby code in a huge repo like this

```
def my_func params
  {
    :k1 => 1,
    :k2 => 2,
    :k3 => 3,
    :k4 => 4,
    :k5 => 5,
    :k6 => 6
  }
end
```

Somehow, few key-value pairs got deleted over time. I want to `git blame` who did this,  But the key-value pair is so common that a `grep` would cause too many false-positives. So is there a way to view a ***function's change*** over all commits?

I tried something like `git log -L /^\s+def my_func/,/^\s+def/ src/to/file.rb`, didn't work. GUI tools like SourceTree has "Log this file", it only shows the diff, so I can not tell which function the change belongs to. I also searched stackoverflow and googled a bit, didn't find a universal way.

Comment: Are you saying those lines are present so many times and deleted so many times you can't search via the -G option to log or with pickaxe?

Comment: @AndrewC yes, and what's worse, I don't really remember what exactly need to be deleted, the first version has lots of k-v pairs, the current version has too few. I need to work out why some got deleted by design or by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can perform a "reverse blame". You simply ask the "difference" from the "new" to the old file, so deletions become addtions and vice versa.

```
git blame --reverse start..end file.ext
```

Where `start` and `end` should be commit signatures.

For each line, it will show the **latest** commit in which the line **appeared**. You can then derive the *next commit* to find out what happened.